# Subsonic: The member 'Days' is not supported

Tags: subsonic

I am using Subsonic (SimpleRepository) to query my SQL 2008 database. I am trying to write a query that will calculate the number of days between two fields and return records where the difference is less than a given number. However, I get a "The member 'Days' is not supported" error.

Can anybody suggest an alternative query?

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
var repository = new SimpleRepository("MyConnection", 
                              SimpleRepositoryOptions.None);
var query = (from c in repository.All<Data.Customer>()
            where c.LastSynchronizedOn == null || 
                  (c.LastSynchronizedOn - c.CreatedOn).Days <= 7)
            select c).Distinct();
```

EDIT:

I tried:

```
(c.LastSynchronizedOn == null || (c.LastSynchronizedOn.Value - c.CreatedOn).Days <= 7)
```

I get the same exception: The member 'Days' is not supported

I also tried:

```
(c.LastSynchronizedOn == null || ((c.LastSynchronizedOn - c.CreatedOn) > new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)))
```

I get: Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of fields `LastSynchronizedOn` and `CreatedOn` as the problem is not related to SubSonic but .Net is complaining (if this is right way to put it) because the expression `(c.LastSynchronizedOn - c.CreatedOn)` might not be returning `DateTime` object.

EDIT:- as per your comment please try this

```
(c.LastSynchronizedOn.Value - c.CreatedOn).Days
```

EDIT (2): the statement

```
(c.LastSynchronizedOn == null || 
  ((c.LastSynchronizedOn - c.CreatedOn) > new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)))
```

returns boolean (true or false)

try this:

```
var repository = new SimpleRepository("MyConnection", 
                          SimpleRepositoryOptions.None);
var query = (from c in repository.All<Data.Customer>()
 where ((c.LastSynchronizedOn ?? 
              new DateTime(c.CreatedOn.Year, c.CreatedOn.Month, 
                          c.CreatedOn.Day).AddDays(-7)) 
     - c.CreatedOn).Days <= 7) select c).Distinct();
```

Comment: LastSynchronizedOn is DateTime? and CreatedOn is DateTime

Comment: The reason why I believe Subsonic is throwing the error an not .NET is because the "Source" of the exception is "Subsonic.Core"

Comment: ...and also the entry at the top of the stack trace is "   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.TSqlFormatter.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)"

Comment: You suggestion yields the same error. I actually looked at the source for the VisitMemberAccess method in TSqlFormatter.cs in Subsonic 3.0.3 and I see on line 216 where NotSupportedException is thrown. That's why I'm looking for an alternate way to write my Linq statement.